# Destructure and assign to new variable at the same time not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I am trying to destructure object and assign it to new variable at the same time:

```
let {x} = a = {x: 'cool'};
console.log(a, x);
```

which outputs:

```
//Object { x: "cool" } cool - in Firefox
//ReferenceError: a is not defined - in Chrome, babel-node
```

Why is there difference and what is the correct behavior?

UPDATE:

This is maybe more generic use case. While this works in all environments:

```
var a = b = {x: 'cool'};
```

this statement is not working in chrome/babel-node:

```
var {x} = a = {x: 'cool'}; //SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

There is also different error message when using `var` instead of `let`.

Comment: The problem is, as the error message says, `a` is not defined. `let a = b = c` does **not** define `b`. Firefox may be doing some default declaration for you, eg in the console.

Comment: @torazaburo that's correct. But `let a = b = c` is possible in firefox (not in chrome)

Comment: For me, in babel-node `var a = b = {x: 'cool'};` gives a ReferenceError, as of course it should. The difference in error messages between `let` and `var` could be related to support of `let` in different environments. `var {x} = a = {x: 'cool'};` in babel-node does not give the error you report; it gives me the same ReferenceError, again as it should.

Comment: @torazaburo so chrome behavior is correct?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you say is working or not working and generating what error in what environment. I suggest adding a little table to your question. Meanwhile, why don't you just write correct code instead of worrying about different environments reporting errors in different ways?

Comment: @torazaburo I am just curious how it works and what is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `a` is not defined. `let a = b = c` does not define `b`. You need to say

```
let a = {x: 1}, {x} = a;
```

Firefox doesn't support `let`, so I'm wondering how your example worked there at all. See https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/.